# Append/Add the property to array of objects if match found using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, for-loop, object

I have two array of objects, in which if `id` and `aid` property values match then append the property `code` to `arr1` and return the result

```
var arr1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "xxx", cn: "IN" },
  { id: 2, name: "yyy", cn: "MY" },
  { id: 3, name: "zzz", cn: "SG" },
]

var arr2 = [
  { aid: 1, code: "finance" },
  { aid: 2, code: "others" },
  { aid: 4, code: "finance" },
  { aid: 5, code: "product" },
]
```

Expected result:

```
var arr1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "xxx", cn: "IN", code: 'finance'},
  { id: 2, name: "yyy", cn: "MY", code: 'others'},
  { id: 3, name: "zzz", cn: "SG", code: ''},
]
```

I tried

```
var result = arr1.map(e=> ({
  ...e,
  code: arr2.map(i=>i.code)
})
```

Comment: How big are the expected arrays, and will `arr1` always have every ID of `1..n`, in order, inside it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first find matching item in `arr2` and them create the composed item.

Try like this:

```js
var arr1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "xxx", cn: "IN" },
  { id: 2, name: "yyy", cn: "MY" },
  { id: 3, name: "zzz", cn: "SG" },
];

var arr2 = [
  { aid: 1, code: "finance" },
  { aid: 2, code: "others" },
  { aid: 4, code: "finance" },
  { aid: 5, code: "product" },
];

const result = arr1.map((item) => {
  const match = arr2.find((o) => o.aid === item.id);
  return { ...item, code: match ? match.code : '' };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This does not put " code: '' " in the final result which is a requirement.

Comment: I ran your code.It does not put the empty code in case of no match. I am talking about this scenario:{ id: 3, name: "zzz", cn: "SG", code: ''} in your case it is this: {id: 3, name: 'zzz', cn: 'SG'}

Comment: did not notice it in the question, updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you require with a loop over `arr1` looking for matches in `arr2` using `filter()`. This will add the `code` property to the existing `arr1` array without creating a new array instance.

Note that this logic assumes that there will only ever be 0 or 1 matches in `arr2`.

```js
var arr1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "xxx", cn: "IN" },
  { id: 2, name: "yyy", cn: "MY" },
  { id: 3, name: "zzz", cn: "SG" },
]

var arr2 = [
  { aid: 1, code: "finance" },
  { aid: 2, code: "others" },
  { aid: 4, code: "finance" },
  { aid: 5, code: "product" },
]

arr1.forEach(o1 => o1.code = arr2.filter(o2 => o2.aid === o1.id)[0]?.code || ''); 
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the most optimal solution but this definitely works for your case:

```
let result = arr1.map((outerObj) => {
    // First we try to find the index of the matching object
    let index = arr2.findIndex((innerObj) => {
        return outerObj.id == innerObj.aid;
    });

    // In case of no match, set case as "" as per requirement
    if(index == -1) {
        outerObj.code = "";
        return outerObj;
    }

    // If a match is found, then combine the two objects.
    let mergedObj = { ...outerObj, ...arr2[index]}; 

    // aid is not needed in the result, Who wants aids anyway? 
    delete mergedObj.aid;
    return mergedObj;
});
```

If not more optimal, then definitely there could be smaller code but I think the code should be clear and readable rather than being smaller.

Answer (score 0):

First, massage the data into a format for fast manipulation; then manipulate.

The following:

1. Puts every item in `arr2` into a map, keyed on `aid`
2. Enumerates `arr1` once, looking into the map for each item to see if there is a corresponding code

Performance: O(N).

```js
var arr1= [
  {id:1, name: "xxx", cn: "IN"},
  {id:2, name: "yyy", cn: "MY"},
  {id:3, name: "zzz", cn: "SG"} ]

var arr2 = [
  { aid: 1, code: "finance"},
  { aid: 2, code: "others"},
  { aid: 4, code: "finance"},
  { aid: 5, code: "product"} ]

const map = arr2.reduce((p,c) => p.set(c.aid, c), new Map)

arr1.forEach((i) => i.code = map.get(i.id)?.code || '')

console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**we can get like this too**

```js
var arr1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "xxx", cn: "IN" },
  { id: 2, name: "yyy", cn: "MY" },
  { id: 3, name: "zzz", cn: "SG" },
]

var arr2 = [
  { aid: 1, code: "finance" },
  { aid: 2, code: "others" },
  { aid: 4, code: "finance" },
  { aid: 5, code: "product" },
]

const fun = (ar, ar2)=>{
const getResult = ar.map((e)=> {
  const Data ={
    id : e.id,
    name : e.name,
    cn : e.cn,
    code : ar2.find((e2)=> e2.aid===e.id)?.code || ""
}
    return Data;
})
return getResult
}
console.log(fun(arr1, arr2))
```

Answer (score 0):

**we can use`find` method too**

```js
var arr1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "xxx", cn: "IN" },
  { id: 2, name: "yyy", cn: "MY" },
  { id: 3, name: "zzz", cn: "SG" },
]

var arr2 = [
  { aid: 1, code: "finance" },
  { aid: 2, code: "others" },
  { aid: 4, code: "finance" },
  { aid: 5, code: "product" },
]

arr1.forEach(e => e.code = arr2.find(d => d.aid === e.id)?.code || ''); 
console.log(arr1);
```